# Require a method to be run or else stop current method

Tags: php, oop, controller

I'm looking for a way to require a method (b) to be run inside of another method (a)?  I can't use construct because I want the argument of the function set inside the method (a).  I also don't want the method (a) to be run if the required method (b) isn't executed.

Example:

```
class baseController {
 protected function _require($blah) {
   # Required code
 }
}

class controller extends baseController {
 public function allmethods() {
    $this->_require('blah')
    # CODE
 }
 public function fail() {
    # CODE WITHOUT _require() NOT RUN
 }
}
```

I know I can set a variable in the required method (b), then check to see if the variable is true in the method (a), but that would require me inputting the check into every method (a).  I was wondering if there is a way to do it by default, so I don't have to insert code into every method (a) checking to see if _require() was run.

Comment: You could do a stack trace, but it's probably easier to do what you're saying you don't want to do - wrap it in a function for ease...?

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a way around that but it would be pointless for me to add a check in every method because it is supposed to be a failsafe for me, or anyone else, who develops a controller and if the check has to be coded in, then it isn't much of a failsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to find an exact solution for what I wanted but the way I went about this may help someone else in the future.

For more information, the main reason I wanted this was so the app could determine if a user had access to the page by setting an access id (referred to my script as `$page`).  While I could set access levels based on the action name, it would create a lot of redundancies and conflicts based on different modules, controllers, etc.

How I went about this was altering my Router to instead of calling the action directly, I set it to call the action through an execute function.

**Router**

```
try {
   $controller = new $controllerName;
   $controller->execute($actionName);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   ...
}
```

Then in my baseController (which is extended by every controller) I added the execute() and also a checkAccess which would only return true or false based on if the user had access.  This refers to another class (Access) that consults the db on access levels.

**baseController**

```
final public function execute($action) {
    $actionMethod = '_action'.$action;
    $accessMethod = '_access'.$action;
    if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethod)) {
        throw new Exception('Action method not defined.');
    }
    if (!method_exists($this, $accessMethod)) {
        throw new Exception('Access method not defined.');
    }
    $page = $this->$accessMethod();
    if (strtolower($page) != 'public' and !Access::check($page)) {
        throw new Exception("Access denied for action $action.");
    }
    $this->$actionMethod();
}

final public function checkAccess($action) {
    $actionMethod = '_action'.$action;
    $accessMethod = '_access'.$action;
    if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethod) or !method_exists($this, $accessMethod)) {
        return false;
    }

    $page = $this->$accessMethod;
    if (strtolower($page) == 'public' or Access::check($page)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly, now I can set two different protected methods in the controller (action/access).  If either is missing, execute() will throw the related exception and stop running.

**Example Controller**

```
class Controller extends baseController {
  protected function _accessTest() {
    return 'access_page_id';
  }
  protected function _actionTest() {
    ...code here...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically it can't be done in the way you have described, but you can wrap any controller into a proxy object / decorator like so:

```
class ControllerWrapper
{
    private $controller;

    public function __construct(baseController $controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    public function __call($method, array $arguments)
    {
        $this->controller->_require('blah');
        return call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $method], $arguments);
    }
}

$wrapper = new ControllerWrapper($controller);
$wrapper->allmethods();
```

Then exclusively use this wrapper to do everything; it will make sure that `_require()` method gets called.

Two downsides of this approach:

1. You have little control over the argument that gets passed the `_require()`.
2. You will not have any code completion goodness that some editors will provide.

I guess the best way is to have something throw an exception if `_require()` hasn't been called.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Your answer is similar in ways to what I ended up doing which I will post here shortly for future reference for others.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the "Template Method" pattern.

Create a base with the methods for interface.

Then the implementation in the base class will call the derived class implemented

```
version:class baseController {
  protected function _require($blah) {
   # Required code
  }
  public function oneOfAllMethods() {
    $this->_require($blah)
    $this->_oneOfAllMethods()
  }
  function _oneOfAllMethods() {
    $this->fail()
  }
  public function fail() {
    #some code for failure 
  }

}

class controller extends baseController {
  public function _allmethods() {
     #already called $this->_require('blah')
     # CODE
  }

}
```

That way you can call require() method before or after derived class code.
By the way I don't know PHP so, apologies for syntax errors